# Why is enpoint.sh not creating a cert or a config directory

Tags: aps

Why is enpoint.sh not creating a cert or a config directory. When I use the script, it creates and deploys the scripts successfully.
However the config folder and cert is not created. 
Are there any steps I am missing

CONGRATULATIONS! Endpoint configured SUCCESSFULLY

Endpoint url: ......CounterMgmt

Answer (score 1):

This script is not supposed to create the config directory or certificates. It only unpacks the scripts from the package and creates an .htaccess files to properly redirect incoming requests.

The config folder and certificates are created when you provision a fist application instance.